# Bootstrap Datepicker not displaying selected date as highlighted

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I was trying to implement bootstrap datepicker on start date and end date.
When I select start date I update selected value into end date, but when I click on end date datepicker opens up but it does not highlight selected date.

Here is my code:

```
$('#start_date, #end_date').datepicker();

$('#start_date').on('changeDate', function (selected) {
    $('#end_date').val($(this).val());
    $(this).datepicker('hide');
});
```

and js fiddle link is: 
[Js fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/amit4mins/qcw0dcaL/9/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to set value to the picker using [`setDate`](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html#setdate) instead of jQuery `val()`.

Note that [`changeDate`](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html#changedate) event [receives extra data](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/events.html#events) including the selected date. You can use `date` attribute to set new value in your `changeDate` listner.

Here a working example:

```js
$('#start_date, #end_date').datepicker();

$('#start_date').on('changeDate', function (selected) {
  $('#end_date').datepicker('setDate', selected.date);
  $(this).datepicker('hide');
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="start_date" />
<input type="text" id="end_date" />
```

Answer (score 1):

This updated fiddle has your answer

https://jsfiddle.net/qcw0dcaL/10/

```
$('#start_date').datepicker();

 $('#start_date').on('changeDate', function (selected) {
         $('#end_date').datepicker('setDate', selected.date);
          $(this).datepicker('hide');
      });
```

You need to use **setDate** instead of setting val.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<div>
    <input type="text" type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker" />
</div>
```